How can I redirect from a WebView back to my app after saving data (avatar) to Firestore?
I’m using a WebView in my Flutter app to allow users to create avatars via Ready Player Me. After the avatar is created, I save the avatar URL to Firestore. Once that’s done, I want to redirect the user back to my app (navigate to a specific screen).
Has anyone implemented something similar or have ideas on how to handle this redirect? Any suggestions or examples would be appreciated!
here is my firebase function
` 
// Inject the currentUserUid into the JavaScript context
const currentUserUid = "${currentUserUid}"; // Ensure it's passed as a string
const storeAvatarApi = "${storeAvatarApi}";
    const frame = document.getElementById('frame');
    const loading = document.getElementById('loading');

    function displayIframe() {
      frame.src = \`https://${subdomain}.readyplayer.me/avatar?frameApi=${token}\`;
      frame.hidden = false;
    };
      
    window.onload = displayIframe;

    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      const json = parse(event);

      if (json?.source !== 'readyplayerme') {
        return;
      }

      // Subscribe to iframe events
      if (json.eventName === 'v1.frame.ready') {
        frame.contentWindow.postMessage(
          JSON.stringify({
            target: 'readyplayerme',
            type: 'subscribe',
            eventName: 'v1.**'
          }),
          '*'
        );
      }

      // Capture avatar URL when the avatar is exported
      if (json.eventName === 'v1.avatar.exported') {
        const avatarUrl = json.data.url;
        window.parent.postMessage({type: 'AVATAR_CREATED', url: avatarUrl}, '*');
        console.log('Avatar URL:', avatarUrl, 'for user:', currentUserUid);
        saveAvatarUrlToFirestore(currentUserUid, avatarUrl);
        frame.hidden = true; // Hide iframe after avatar is exported
        window.location.href = \`https://app.flutterflow.io/avatarCreated?avatarUrl=\${encodeURIComponent(avatarUrl)}\`;

      }

      // Handle user set event (optional)
      if (json.eventName === 'v1.user.set') {
        console.log(\`User with id \${json.data.id} set: \${JSON.stringify(json)}\`);
      }
    });

    // Helper function to parse postMessage events
    function parse(event) {
      try {
        return JSON.parse(event.data);
      } catch (error) {
        return null;
      }
    } 

    // Function to save avatar URL to Firestore or Firebase
    async function saveAvatarUrlToFirestore(currentUserUid, avatarUrl) {
      const response = await fetch(storeAvatarApi, { 
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ currentUserUid, avatarUrl }), // Ensure structured payload
      });
      
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log('Avatar URL saved successfully.');
       re
      } else {
        console.error('Error saving avatar URL:', response.statusText);
      }
    }
  </script>              `

